# Mac apps not seeing iTunes library

Tags: macos, mac, itunes, libraries

I've got an iTunes library of about 6000 songs plus a couple of dozen videos. For some reason, only Front Row and iTunes can see it. When I try to access the library from other applications, such as iMovie, iWeb, or any thing else, I am told that I don't have an iTunes library! Is there anyway to fix this?
I am running Mac OS X 10.5.8 Leopard on an Intel Core 2 Duo iMac from 2006. In fact, I've been having this problem since Mac OS X 10.4.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- back up your itunes library file (normally found in: ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Library)
- Delete the library file.
- Delete ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.itunes.plist
- Run iTunes again and reimport your music library.

If you'd rather not delete the files mentioned, either move them to another place on the disk or archive them into a zip and delete the original.

Comment: Is there a way to do it so I don't have to reimport my music library? I hate to lose all my playlists, ratings, metadata, etc.

Comment: I tried a variation of this method by deleting the iTunes XML file, but it was not recreated and this attempt did not seem to have changed anything. Other idea?

Comment: I'm out of ideas if that didn't work... sorry :(

Comment: Then again, try resetting iPhoto and other apps using the same kinda method. Delete their preferences files and see if that helps. It could be that the other apps are at fault and not iTunes.